# Unknown format in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, format

Im trying to scrape (https://www.aiscore.com/es) stats for every match. I ve discover that the page make requests to an API (https://api.aiscore.com/v1/web/api/match/stats?match_id=9gklzir4l38im7x&lang=4) but when i try to get onto this url a file is downloades in an unknown format.

It's posible to get the data by not downloading anything, also i want to know how can i decrypt that file or what format it is.

That file looks like this if i open with notepad.

```
zy

à*408h


63


10

6337


00

    
10159


32

6828

101
```

Comment: What is your question focused on? Decryption or getting response?

Comment: I want to decrypt the file without downloading